# Facing problem in initialization of components in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, components, initialization

I am a student C# programmer. I am just learning Localization and Globalization. I am just created a button to change the current culture (CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture) of the current thread. But after running this program this button is not working as I need. Button click event I written is like below:

```
    private void BtnLocalized_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo CI = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
        if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture != CI)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CI;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CI;
        }
        else
        {
            CI = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CI;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CI;
        }
    }
```

I also tried calling `InitializeComponent()` method after else block. But it just create another button component without dispossing the current button.

How can I re-initialized this button

**Edit:**
I just want to change the `Text` properties with my current local language set bt this application.

Comment: This looks like a WinForms app, but I'm not sure. Could you please confirm?

Comment: Yes this is a WinForms application.

Comment: What is the expected behavior after the culture change, and how does the observed behavior differ from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The labels of the form are set when the form is created and are not automatically updated.**

There are two options:

1. The easy option is to close and re-open the form;
2. The difficult option is to manually update the labels of all controls of your form. If you look in the "Designer.cs" of your form, you can see how the labels are set. You can duplicate such a mechanism yourself.

I would go for option 1.

Comment: Are there any other option to disposing reinitialize components.

Comment: I believe the options above are the only options. There is no shortcut, at least not with normal .NET framework usage. There may however be tools that help you with this, but I do not know of them.